Equation or inequality in terms of Baker's linear forms in logarithms involving two relatively prime natural numbers
Can you give me an equation or inequality, in terms of linear forms in logarithms, that is valid for only finitely many pairs x, y, where x and y are coprime natural numbers? In other words, I want, for example, an equation or inequality, consisting of linear forms in log x and log y, which holds true if and only if x and y are coprime integers.
